# Check the length of data in a cell and add a zero

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet containing data in the following format:

```
         Col1            Col2
ROW1:    21211     Customer 3873721
ROW2:   101111     Customer 2321422
ROW3:    91214     Customer 2834712
ROW4:   231014     Customer 3729123
```

I need to be able to create a macro that goes through each row and determines the number of characters that make up the row1 data.

For example:

> If data contained in the first cell or ROW1 consisted of a total of 6
>   characters then this will remain the same. If it consisted of 5
>   characters then a zero needs to be added to the front of it.

I'm using Excel 2003.

Comment: your example data is a little confusing.  It looks like you're calling columns rows.  Where is this information to be output? Another sheet, another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA is not needed in this case.  A simple `IF Statement` should do the trick.  Assuming the column you want to evalutate is column A place this in column B and duplicate down the column:

```
=+IF(LEN(A1)=5,"0" & A1,A1)
```

This will work provided all values are 5 or 6 characters long as it appears in your sample data.

Comment: Did this do the trick?  Please accept the answer to the left with a green checkmark if this works.  If not, perhaps more clarification on the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This did work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP may be happy with a Custom Format of:

```
#000000
```

This is easy to apply but mainly may be a good idea because most other ways of prepending a `0` are only possible by conversion of numeric values to strings (as otherwise Excel will automatically strip leading zeros). If that is done selectively (for length 5 but not length 6) a column of what appears to be numbers might end up with mixed types (of different behaviour) and so confuse or inconvenience.